# Kibana to display @timestamp field into a readable format

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I setup an ELK stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana)

I wonder how to display the `@timestamp` field into a readable format which contains this format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

I want the Kibana to display something like `HH:mm:ss DD MM YYYY`

**Note:**

I'd like to configure the `@timestamp` field in Kibana because I don't wanna setup logstash to add additional field just to display timestamp in a readable fasion. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kibana4 (now in beta3) allows you to specify a dateFormat in the settings.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look into that. So this means in Kibana 3 it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field by logstash, say `time_readable`.

```
filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    timeRead = event['@timestamp']
                    event['time_readable'] = timeRead.strftime '%H:%M:%S %d %m %Y'
            "
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion. However, I am trying that as much as possible I don't want to add additional field just to display a readable datetime thinking that I already have the `@timestamp` generated by logstash, I'd like kibana to display it in a readable fashion in the table pane. If you could suggest a config of Kibana, I'd be grateful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change format right in the code of 'Table' panel:
**.../kibana/app/panels/table/module.js**

find original code in the bottom of the file:

```
f.filter("tableLocalTime", function() {
    return function(a, b) {
        return e(b.sort[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    }
```

and change it to what you want, for example:

```
f.filter("tableLocalTime", function() {
    return function(a, b) {
        return e(b.sort[1]).format("DD.MM HH:mm")
    }
```